# Как вывести список на страницу?

Tags: php

```
<label for="otdel">Отдел:</label>
<select name="otdel" size="1">
    <option selected="selected" value="Ленинский">Ленинский</option>
    <option value="1">Парк культуры</option>
    <option value="2">Таганка</option>
    <option value="3">Тверская</option>
    <option value="4">Третьяковка</option>
    <option value="5">Самара</option>
    <option value="6">Казань</option>
    <option value="7">Нижний Новгород</option>
    <option value="8">Тольятти</option>
</select>
```

Из списка данные уходят в таблицу БД `otdel`. Подскажите, как теперь через `array` это вывести на страницу. Или по-другому.

Comment: Непонятно чего именно вы хотите

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="">
    <option value="0"></option>
<?php
    foreach ($departments as $department) {
        if ($selected !== 0 && $selected === $department['id']) {
            echo '<option value="' . $department['id'] . '" selected="selected">' . $department['title'] . '</option>';
                continue;
            }
            echo '<option value="' . $department['id'] . '">' . $department['title'] . '</option>';
        }
?>
</select>
```

`$departments` - это классификатор, т.е. сам список храниться в базе данных, но может храниться и просто массивом...

```
$departments = array(
    array('id' => '1', 'title' => 'Ленинский'),
    array('id' => '2', 'title' => 'Парк культуры')
    ...
);
```

`$selected` - это сохраненное значение из этого же списка.